Represent a vector using a different orthonormal basis
I'm currently reading a book about quantum computing where it is important to represent a vector $|\psi⟩$ with $\| |\psi⟩ \| = 1$ with any given orthonormal basis. Given that $ \{ |b_1⟩, |b_2⟩, ... , |b_n⟩\}$ is a orthonormal basis, then I can represent any $ |\psi⟩ $ as
$$ |\psi⟩ = c_1|b_1⟩ + c_2|b_2⟩ + ... + c_n|b_n⟩ = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k|b_k⟩ $$
Where every $c_i$ ist a complex number. I want to show now that $c_i = ⟨b_i|\psi⟩$
However, I guess I am making a mistake. Here is my approach:
For any $i = 1, ... n$:
$$ c_i = ⟨b_i|\psi⟩ = \left\langle b_i \mid \sum_{k=1}^n c_k |b_k⟩ \right\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n \left\langle b_i \mid  (c_k |b_k⟩) \right\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k^* \left\langle b_i \mid  b_k \right\rangle = c_i^* $$
Where $c_i^*$ is the complex conjugate of $c_i$
Can anyone tell me what my mistake is or show another way to show that $c_i = ⟨b_i|\psi⟩$?
I read about it here on page 112-113 for reference.
The 3rd equality in my approach comes from equation 2.102 (p. 54) and the 4th from equation 2.104 in the referenced book. They are
$$ ⟨V_1, V_2 + V_3⟩ = ⟨V_1, V_2⟩ + ⟨V_1, V_3⟩ $$
$$ ⟨V_1, cV_2⟩ = c^*⟨V_1, V_2⟩ $$

Different people choose to put the conjugate linearity in the first or the second slot, so I'm not going to try to resolve that. But it looks like you've proved $c_i = ⟨b_i|\psi⟩^*$. Is that not good enough?

Why do you keep vertical bars? This is confusing, is this a quantum notation?

With the convention $⟨V_1, cV_2⟩ = c^*⟨V_1, V_2⟩$ and $⟨cV_1, V_2⟩ = c⟨V_1, V_2⟩$ what you get is $c_i=⟨\psi,b_i⟩$, not $⟨b_i,\psi⟩$.

@julio_es_sui_glace yes that is the notation used in quantum computing

@AnneBauval, JonathanZ do you mean that another convention is that $⟨V_1, cV_2⟩= c⟨V_1, V_2⟩$ and then instead $⟨cV_1, V_2⟩ = c*⟨V_1, V2⟩$?

Yes, so do I: see convention variant. But examining your book on GoogleBooks (since your link doesn't work for me), @julio's comment makes me think there is a huge confusion between the notations $⟨u,v⟩$ (inner product) and $⟨u|v⟩$ (Bra-ket).

That is probably a typo : complex scalar products are always linear with respect to the second variable with Dirac notation $-$ and in physics in general, unless it is clearly stated. In consequence, it should be $\langle V_1,cV_2 \rangle = c\langle V_1,V_2 \rangle$.

@Abezhiko yes, I also read about it here now. Thanks a lot!

Notation: it might interest you to know about \| for better spaced double bars. Compare readability: $| \lvert\psi\rangle |$ vs $|| \lvert\psi\rangle ||$.

This is an inconsistency in the book: If one defines the inner product to be linear in the first argument—and thus antilinear in the second argument, as stated in Eq. (2.103) & (2.104) of the book you're working with—then the basis expansion formula for any orthonormal basis $\{|b_0\rangle,\ldots,|b_{n-1}\rangle\}\subset\mathbb C^n$ (Eq. (4.33) in the book) is given by
$$
|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|b_0\rangle\,|b_0\rangle+\ldots+\langle\psi|b_{n-1}\rangle\,|b_{n-1}\rangle
$$
for all $|\psi\rangle\in\mathbb C^n$. This follows at once from the computation that you already did yourself, i.e., by starting with $|\psi\rangle=\sum_jc_j|b_j\rangle$ and then computing $\langle \psi|b_k\rangle$ for all $k=0,\ldots,n-1$.
Similarly, if the inner product is defined to be linear in the second argument—as is standard in quantum information—then Eq. (4.33) in the book holds, i.e., only then is $|\psi\rangle=\sum_j\langle b_j|\psi\rangle|b_j\rangle$ for all $\psi$, as the authors claim.
